# Iterating through a nested Leftsequence

Tags: python, iteration, sequence

I just wondered how can you iterate through a nested Leftsequence?

I made a left sequence out with the following code:

```
def leftSeq(s):
    ls = "leer"
    for i in range(len(s), 0, -1):
        ls = (l[i - 1], ls)
    return ls

l = [1,2,3]
```

Output = `(1, (2, (3, 'leer')))`

How do I iterate through it?

Comment: Your indentation doesn't make sense. Paste your code, highlight it, and then click the code icon in the editor window (or use the shortcut `ctrl+C`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make an iterator for such left sequences:

```
def left_iterator(lseq):
    while isinstance(lseq,tuple) and len(lseq) == 2:
        first, lseq = lseq
        yield first
    yield lseq

#test:

x = (1, (2, (3, 'leer')))
for i in left_iterator(x):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
leer
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop like so and nest through `ls`:

```
x = (1, (2, (3, 'leer'))) #=leftSeq(l)

while len(x) > 1:
    print(x)
    x = x[1]
```

```
(1, (2, (3, 'leer')))
(2, (3, 'leer'))
(3, 'leer')
leer
```